# PHP - Codeigniter : Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open for reading, File does not exist

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, phpexcel, xls

My current CI project is now handling files. I want to upload the xls| xlsx files to the server and then import Excel data into the Database table.

As the first part, the uploaded file was successfully, and I uploaded the files to the **uploads** folder in the same level of **application, system, assets**. Now I want to load this file and import those contents to DB. I'm using **PHPExcel** to do this operation.

Here is my Controller

```
$this->load->library('phpexcel');
$this->load->library('PHPExcel/iofactory');

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objReader= IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$objPHPExcel=$objReader->load(BASE_URL().'uploads/Data_Report.xls');

$objWorksheet=$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$this->load->model('datas_model');

for($i=2;$i<=77;$i++) {

     $client_name= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$i)->getValue();
     $client_address= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getValue();
     $data_inp=array('name'=>$client_name, 'address'=>$client_address);
     $this->datas_model->add_data($data_inp);
   }
```

And here is my View

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('../settings_controller/upload_data/do_upload');?>

   <div class="custom-file-upload">
        <input type="file" id="file" name="userfile" multiple/>
   </div>
   <div class="button-container-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="updown-btn" type="submit" style="height:45px;">Upload </button>
   </div>

<?php echo "</form>"?>
```

When I'm running, it shows me an error `Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with the message 'Could not open http://localhost/myproject/uploads/Data_Report.xls for reading! File does not exist.'`

when i put that Data_Report.xls file inside **htdocs** , it works succesfully .

The problem is when using BASE_URL().'uploads/Data_Report.xls'. But the file is physically there. I verified by pasting localhost/myproject/uploads/Data_Report.xls on the URL, and it downloaded successfully.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is the case, but you should try to add the absolute path in file system and not the path of the url.

like:

```
/var/www/YourProject/public/uploads/Data_Report.xls
```

and not

```
yourUrl.com/uploads/Data_Report.xls
```

how to get the absolute path (no hardcoding!)
with codeigniter you can use:

```
FCPATH   -> '/'
BASEPATH -> '/system/'
APPPATH  -> '/application/'
```

so I dont remember the structure of codeigniter but I got this from google,
so do something like this:

```
APPPATH.'public/uploads/what_ever.xls';
```

Comment: now i get the solution when provide the relative path by removing base_url.but is this correct method to solve this problem .? becouse it do not uses the base_url .? so is there any problem in future (hosting)

Comment: updated my answer for not hardcoding the absolute path, and tell me if it works

Comment: yes it is already worked when tried ./myproject/uploads/Data_Report.xls without BASE_URL()

Comment: use the codeigniter paths so if you move the project directories it will still work. Please accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you copying the xls file to your "upload" directory on form submission?

It will be something like below:

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
{
   throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
}
```

by default, the file is uploaded in the temp directory (in your case it seems to be `htdocs`) and needs to be moved to the target path of choice before performing Excel open through PHP Excel library.

Answer (score 0):

first, check the upload_max_filesize in php.ini file.
if your excel size < to upload_max_filesize size this error will happend.